# Prove that $\left(r^{2} \cos 2 \theta, r^{2} \sin 2 \theta\right)$ is on upper half-space

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Prove $\left(r^{2} \cos 2 \theta, r^{2} \sin 2 \theta\right)$ is on the upper half space.

( assuming $x=r \cos \theta, y=r \sin \theta$ for $r>0,0<\theta<\pi / 2$)

Is there rigorous proof without substituing the endpoints?

Comment: You likely want to constrain $\theta < \pi/4$...

Comment: Thank you guys, I meant the upper half space

Comment: @matmat: What does $(r^2\cos2\theta,r^2\sin2\theta)$ even mean when you go on to write $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$? Also, by "upper half space" do you mean "upper half-*plane*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that your values are in the upper half space, it suffices to show that its $y$ coordinate is positive, i.e. that $r^2\sin 2\theta$ is positive for $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Well, it is clear that $r^2 > 0$ and also recall that $\sin(x) \geq 0$ for $ 0\leq x\leq\pi$. Taking $x = 2\theta$, we get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you very much.